# Is the square of a vector bundle trivial?

Tags: algebraic-topology, vector-bundles

Let $E$ be a smooth vector bundle with a metric. 
Then $E^*$ is isomorphic to $E$ by mapping $v \in E$ to $\langle v, \circ\rangle \in E^*$.

Because $E \otimes E^*$ is a trivial bundle, can we say that the square $E \otimes E \cong E \otimes E^*$ is also trivial ?

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but can’t you only say that that $E \otimes E^*$ admits a trivial summand of dimension 1?

Comment: $E \otimes E^*$ is isomorphic to the endomorphism bundle rather then trivial bundle. $\text{End}(E)$ is trivial when $E$ is a line bundle but I cannot come up with  the counterexamples on the spot in general.

Comment: As @Mihail said, it needs the additional condition that $E$ is a line bundle. I do not think the square is a trivial bundle, but, ... I cannot reveal where i misunderstand.

Comment: The misunderstanding lies at the point where you say that $E \otimes E^*$ is a trivial bundle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Mihail's answer, they are taking the tensor product of complex line bundles as complex bundles, but you could also take the tensor product as real bundles. This gives rise to examples where $E\otimes E$ is non-trivial.

First, note that $E\otimes E \cong E^*\otimes E \cong \operatorname{End}(E)$. This bundle is always orientable, because $w_1(E\otimes F) = \operatorname{rank}(F)w_1(E) + \operatorname{rank}(E)w_1(F)$, so $E\otimes E$ has an Euler class. As $\operatorname{End}(E)$ has a nowhere-zero section, namely $\operatorname{id}_E$, we have $e(E\otimes E) = 0$. In particular, you cannot use the Euler class to demonstrate that such a bundle is non-trivial.

Now let $E$ be a real orientable rank two bundle. Choosing an orientation for $E$, we can view $E$ as a complex line bundle. Then

$$\operatorname{End}(E) = \operatorname{End}_{\mathbb{C}}(E)\oplus\overline{\operatorname{End}}_{\mathbb{C}}(E)$$

where the terms of the decomposition are complex linear and complex antilinear endomorphisms respectively. If $J$ denotes the almost complex structure on $E$, then the decomposition is given by $L \mapsto \frac{1}{2}(L - JLJ) + \frac{1}{2}(L+JLJ)$. Note that $\operatorname{id}_E$ defines a nowhere-zero section of $\operatorname{End}_{\mathbb{C}}(E)$, so $\operatorname{End}_{\mathbb{C}}(E) \cong \varepsilon_{\mathbb{C}}^1$ (alternatively, $\operatorname{End}_{\mathbb{C}}(E) \cong E^*\otimes_{\mathbb{C}} E \cong \varepsilon^1_{\mathbb{C}}$). On the other hand, a complex anti-linear endomorphism of $E$ can be viewed as a complex linear homomorphism $E \to \overline{E}$, so

$$\overline{\operatorname{End}}_{\mathbb{C}}(E) \cong \operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbb{C}}(E, \overline{E}) \cong E^*\otimes_{\mathbb{C}}\overline{E} \cong \overline{E}\otimes_{\mathbb{C}}\overline{E} \cong \overline{E}^2.$$

Therefore

\begin{align*}
p_1(\operatorname{End}(E)) &= p_1(\varepsilon_{\mathbb{C}}^1\oplus\overline{E}^2)\\ 
&= p_1(\overline{E}^2)\\ 
&= -c_2(\overline{E}^2\otimes_{\mathbb{R}}\mathbb{C})\\ 
&= -c_2(\overline{E}^2\oplus E^2)\\ 
&= -c_1(\overline{E}^2)c_1(E^2)\\ 
&= -4c_1(\overline{E})c_1(E)\\ 
&= 4c_1(E)^2.
\end{align*}

So, for example, if $E = \mathcal{O}(1)$ over $\mathbb{CP}^2$, then $E\otimes E$ is non-trivial as $p_1(E\otimes E) = 4\alpha^2 \neq 0$ where $\alpha = c_1(\mathcal{O}(1))$ is a generator of $H^2(\mathbb{CP}^2; \mathbb{Z})$.

Comment: Nicely done. :)

Comment: @TedShifrin: Thanks! It came almost directly from [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/267955/21564).

Comment: I was purposely avoiding complex bundles, but it was silly. I'm still curious if you know what the answer is for $E\to\tilde G(2,4)$. :)

Comment: @TedShifrin: As $\tilde{G}(2, 4) = S^2\times S^2$, $E$ is of the form $\mathcal{O}(m, n)$ for some $m$ and $n$. Any chance you know what $m$ and $n$ are? I can show that $p_1(E\otimes E) = 8mn$.

Comment: Great point. Since the two factors correspond to self-dual and anti-self-dual planes, we should be able to figure that out. :)  BTW, wonderful to see you've finished and are now into the next chapter of your life :)

Comment: After a bit of computation, I believe that for the first factor, $m=1$. Presumably, $n=\pm 1$ and so $p_1\ne 0$.

Comment: @TedShifrin: Thanks Ted, now I just need to figure out how to do this research thing. I'd like to nail down $m$ and $n$, so if you have any further insights, let me know.

Comment: OK, so, as I surmised, $n=-1$, Michael. :)

Answer (score 2):

For any line bundle, real or complex, $E\otimes E^*$ is in fact trivial. In the real case, since $E^*\cong E$, as you asserted, we know that $E\otimes E$ is indeed trivial. The "universal" example is the Möbius line bundle $E$ over the circle. It is, of course, nontrivial (corresponding to the generator of $H^1(S^1,\Bbb Z/2)$). However, its square corresponds to take a Möbius strip with two half-twists, and this is, as you can easily check, isomorphic to the trivial bundle. In particular, it has a nowhere zero section.

**EDIT**: Mike Miller suggested to me in chat that you consider $E^*\otimes E$ with $E = \varepsilon^1 \oplus \Lambda^2 (T\Bbb RP^2)$ as a rank-$2$ bundle on $\Bbb RP^2$. A Stiefel-Whitney class computation shows that $w_2(E\otimes E)\ne 0$, and so the bundle must be nontrivial.

I would like to do the computation with $E$ the tautological bundle on $\tilde G(2,4)$ (the Grassmannian of oriented $2$-planes in $\Bbb R^4$). It shouldn't be too bad to get $p_1(E\otimes E)$.

Comment: I think OP asked about vector bundles of arbitrary rank

Comment: If $L$ is a real line bundle, then its structure group can be reduced to the orthonormal group $O(1)$ and which is the set $\{1,-1\}$. Thus the square bundle can have transition functions whose values are in the set $\{1^2,(-1)^2\}=\{1\}$. Thus, the square of a real line bundle is trivial.
I came up with a proof from a concrete example (Mobius strip). Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. I'm still working on a (real) example with rank $\ge 2$ for which it is "easy" to see that $E\otimes E^*$ cannot be trivial.

Answer (score 1):

**My answer holds for the complex vector bundles rather than real** (Thank you @ConnorMalin for this remark in the comments below)

You are correct in the case of (real) line bundles but in general $E \otimes E^*$ is not a trivial bundle.

It is known that there is a group isomorphism between $H^2(M,\mathbb Z)$ and the complex line bundles over $M$ given by the first Chern class. Pick $M$ with nontrivial $H^2$ for example consider $\mathbb{CP}^2$. Let $E$ be the tautological bundle over $\mathbb{CP}^2$. Then $E\otimes E$ is not trivial because $c_1(E)$ is a generator of $H^2(M,\mathbb Z)=\mathbb{Z}$ and hence $c_1 (E\otimes E)$ is twice the generator.

Comment: And the real line bundles will be classified by the cohomology with $\mathbb{Z/2Z}$ coefficients so it is not surprising that the group of (real) line bundles have a 2-torsion.

Comment: The Picard  group is the set of all holomorphic line bundles. And the isomorphism between $E$ and $E^*$ is smooth, but not holomorphic, because a metric is only smooth even if on the complex manifold. Thus, I want to get a counter example 
  in the case of non-holomorphic category, namely, in case of smooth real line bundle $E$, there is a counter example of $E\otimes E$ is not trivial.

Comment: My cohomologies are singular and they classify the smooth complex line bundles. There is no business with holomorphic category. You might be confusing with sheaf cohomology.

Comment: I confused, sorry. I think the reason that the square is not  trivial in your example is that there is no non-degenerate  holomorphic sections  of the bundle $E^*\otimes E^*$. If there is a holomorphic  quadratic form of a line bundle $L$ on a complex manifold $M$, then $L \otimes L$ will be trivial, but the existence of such holomorphic quadratic form is difficult to assume in general cases. Thank you.

Comment: It seemed to me like the question was about real bundles and real tensor products.

Comment: @ConnorMalin I was careless. Thank you for this remark!

Comment: @JeanBillie square is nontrivial because trivial complex bundles have trivial Chern class(and the square has nontrivial first chern class).

Comment: I understand @Mihail.  In complex cases, the square $E\otimes E$ of any non-trivial line bundle $E$ is never trivial, because $c_1(E \otimes E) =2 c_1(E) \neq 0$.

Comment: @JeanBillie This is not true. Find any space with 2-torsion in the second cohomology for a counterexample.

Comment: @JeanBillie As Connor points out your argument does not holds in general but it is fine when we consider the example of $\mathbb{CP}^2$ which does not have torsion in cohomologies.